# Is there a way for me to know when an notification goes off?

Tags: java, android

For an app I'm developing, I need to know when a notification comes up, be it from an app or text message. I'm new to app development and I'm lost around this subject. I've looked at the NotificationListenerService but I'm going in circles at this point.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you want to detect any kind of notifications from all resources or only the ones for your app?

Comment: Any kind of notification from all resources.

Comment: This tutorial may help you : http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html

Comment: Thanks for the help!